# How do I iterate through an arraylist?

Tags: java, jquery

I have a `GetArray.jsp` with java code that outputs an array of the form :

```
[{"value":"Hi","id":"77","label":"Hi there"},
{"value":"Hello","id":"21","label":"Hello there"}]
```

The array is declared like this in java :

```
ArrayList<SomeType> arr = new ArrayList<SomeType>();
```

I do an ajax load to that jsp like this :

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('.container').load('GetArray.jsp', function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        $.each(responseText, function (index, response) {
            $('.main').append(response.value);
            $('.main').append('<br /><br /><br /><br />');
        });
    });
});
```

But I am not getting jQuery to print anything, even though the JSP does return the array mentioned on top.

I know its a json, but how do I print it?

Comment: Are you sure you understand how `load()` works, maybe you should try `$.get()` instead ?

Comment: Are you missing a `'` after `GetArray.jsp` ?

Comment: Alex .. corrected it. 

Adeneo .. I know its a java array. I would like to convert it to a javascript array if thats possible.

Comment: `$.getJSON` would be more appropriate here than `$.load`

Comment: Thanks Kevin. That works. Could you put that as an answer so I could accept it.